# How to stop searching if a string occurs before another string in Regex

Tags: regex

I am new to regex especially advanced regex (look behind or look ahead),

I have two lines,

1. choose balls if they are in red bag, or they are in green bag
2. choose balls if they are in green bag, or they are in red bag

I wanted to have a match only if the line has red before the 1st 'bag'. And not match if line has red after 1st 'bag' (so match 1 and not 2)

If I use the following regex,

```
sort.+?red(?!bag)
```

Or

```
sort.+?(?!bag)red
```

It still seems to match line 2 in both cases.

Any hint/answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one does the job:

```
^(?:(?!\bbag\b).)*\bred\b.+?\bbag\b
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
                # tempered greedy token
  (?:           # start non capture group
    (?!         # negative lookahead
      \bbag\b   # "bag" surrounded with word boundary, not matching bags or airbag
    )           # end lookahead
    .           # any character
  )*            # end group, may appear 0 or more times
  \bred\b       # "red" surrounded with word boundary, not matching tired or redition
  .+?           # 1 or more any character, not greedy
  \bbag\b       # "bag" surrounded with word boundary
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WiTnUI/2)